# About Computer Architecture

Tags: linux

There are three artictures in jdk8 source code : 'linux_sparc' 'linux_x86' 'linux_zero'.

I know 'linux_sparc' 'linux_x86' but I don't understand what does the 'linux_zero' mean?.

Comment: Who says there are only three architectures in the Linux source code? Modern Linux versions support many more... MIPS and ARM and PowerPC to name a few. And what version of the Linux kernel are you looking at here?

Comment: There is nothing like that in Linux source code. Where did you get this information from?

Comment: I get this from jdk8 source code. @n.m.@Dan Lenski.There exsits 'globals_linux_sparc.hpp' 'globals_linux_x86.hpp' 'globals_linux_zero.hpp'

Comment: I just want to know the difference between zero x86 sparc etc.

Comment: jdk8 is not Linux. Edited the question to reflect the facts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Zero" is not an architecture. It is a mode of operation of JDK that uses no assembler and no architecture-specific knowledge, and therefore should (in theory at least) work on any architecture.